# Gstreamer - Unix time in a name

Tags: format, gstreamer, http-live-streaming

I use gstreamer for making video files from my USB camera.
The name of the every file must contain the current unix time.
It's possible to paste the time in a name by ffmpeg:

```
 ffmpeg -i /dev/video1 -c copy file%s.ts
```

As a result: `file1543843169.ts`

Is it possible to make the same name in Gstreamer?
If I try to add %s I get `file<null>.ts`

Thanks is advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty brief description.. But are you looking something like that (for Linux for example):

```
[..] ! filesink location=file$(date +%s).ts
```

Comment: This only produces the date once at the time the pipeline starts, and then the same value is used for all file names.  Is there a way to have every file produced by multifilesink named using a new time?

Comment: That would make identifying files belonging to the same stream really hard, wouldn't it?

Comment: Hm I guess it could still have a basename, but no, I don't think its possible.

Comment: Florian if you're time/date-stamping, it would result in each saved file having a unique name, such as Jan0119-00:00:01.001. jan0119frame-00:00:01.036, etc.